# Is a cfront tool available for the new C++?

Tags: c++, c, cfront

Is a cfront tool available for the new C++? For any other modern languages?

Comment: Are you asking is there any compiler that writes C code?

Answer (score 4):

[Comeau C/C++](http://comeaucomputing.com/) is a C-generating C++ compiler, like cfront.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by “cfront tool”? Cfront was the first C++ compiler. But since failure to add exception support, [it has been discontinued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront). Modern C++ is way beyond the scope of Cfront.

> For any other modern languages?

And what do you mean by that? If you mean whether other compilers exist that compile a high-level language into C code then the answer is yes, there are plenty. The [Glasgow Haskell Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) is just one out of many.

Comment: The first cfront converted C++ code into C code, so you could compile it on a C compiler.  I gather he's looking for a C++ to C translator.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a number of languages, at least in their infancy, just "compile" to C code, letting a good compiler (often gcc...) to generate optimized native code. I think [GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc/) is (for some implementations?) such language, and there are some others I don't recall.

I know also lua2c, converting Lua code to C.

Answer (score 2):

[Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/)

> Bigloo enables full connections
>   between Scheme and C programs, between
>   Scheme and Java programs, and between
>   Scheme and C# programs.

[Gambit-C](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

[Gambit benchmarks](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Gambit_benchmarks)